# Cron job not working all the way. and Python is only half working on my script

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, cron

I have been at it for hours trying to get this twitter bot to work on autopilot.

Here is the deal. First off I'm using the Raspberry Pi as a platform for running my bots 24/7.

The Pi is setup to work through ssh.

I have executed these commands

```
sudo pip install TwitterFollowBot

sudo pip install twitter
```

python 2.7 is already installed. 
I go ahead to set up my dir folder for my project

```
mkdir bot
```

and

```
cd bot 
mkdir newsbot
cd newsbot
```

I created my bot under nano newsbot.py, here is an example.

```
from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot

my_bot = TwitterBot()

my_other_bot = TwitterBot("config.txt")

my_bot.sync_follows()
my_bot.auto_fav("news", count=1)
```

For Testing purposes I just used a single command.

Everything works when I type in

```
python newsbot.py
```

no problems working

But Here is the problem...
It only works when I'm in the directory not outside of it. for example
this works
    python newsbot.py
I turn it into an executable because I'm about to assign a cron job to this python script.. 
but this gives me an error

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/bot/newsbot/newsbot.py
```

here is the error message IF I'm outside of the directory.. Such as if I am cd ~
and then run this line

```
File "/home/pi/bot/newsbot/newsbot.py", line 6, in <module>
    my_bot = TwitterBot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TwitterFollowBot-v2.0.1-py2.7.egg/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.bot_setup(config_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TwitterFollowBot-v2.0.1-py2.7.egg/TwitterFollowBot/__init__.py", line 78, in bot_setup
    with open(config_file, "r") as in_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.txt'
```

So I know */1 * * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/bot/newsbot/newsbot.py
isn't going to work.

So I think of an work around. I would create a shell script that would execute the python script

```
#!/bin/sh
python newsbot.py >> cron.txt
```

and so when a cron job to work it only create a blank cron.txt file...

I don't know what I'm doing at this point. I'm sure the problem is some where in the TwitterFollowBot not being installed properly... Any help or ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Your script is saying

```
my_other_bot = TwitterBot("config.txt")
```

But the crontab does not know where this file is because its environment is quite limited. It will probably look for it in `/`.

So you need to use an absolute path, so that it knows where to find the file:

```
my_other_bot = TwitterBot("/path/to/config.txt")
```

---

For more info about typical problems, see [Tips for debugging cron issues from crontab wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info).